# Why if $\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(L)$ and $x\in L$ then $\phi(\operatorname{ad} x)\phi^{-1}=\operatorname{ad}\phi(x)$?

Tags: lie-algebras, automorphism-group

> An automorphism of the form $\exp(\operatorname{ad}x)$, $\operatorname{ad}x$ nilpotent, is called **inner**; more generally, the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}L$ generated by these is denoted $\operatorname{Int}L$ and its elements called inner automorphisms. It is a *normal* subgroup: If $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}L, x\in L$, then $\phi(\operatorname{ad}x)\phi^{-1}=\operatorname{ad}\phi(x)$, whence $\phi\exp(\operatorname{ad}x)\phi^{-1}=\exp(\operatorname{ad}\phi(x))$.

I don't quite understand why $\phi(\operatorname{ad}x)\phi^{-1}=\operatorname{ad}\phi(x)$. Suppose the left-hand side is applied on $y\in L$, then we get $\phi(\operatorname{ad}x)\phi^{-1}y = \phi[x, \phi^{-1}y]$, while if the right-hand side is applied on $y\in L$, then we get $[\phi(x), y]$.

We don't have $\phi([x, \phi^{-1}(y)])=[\phi(x), y]$, do we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  An automorphism of a Lie algebra respects all of its structure, including the bracket.  So for $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}L$ and $x,y\in L$ we have $\phi([x,y])=[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$.

Comment: Ah, an automorphism is a homomorphism, and a homomorphism respects the bracket.

Comment: @PJMiller: That's right.  Although, in your question we need $\phi$ to be more than a homomorphism, because we are using the map $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks Jared!